# Redirect stuck after initial redirect within middleware .net core

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core

Having a strange issue in .net core 
I've created some custom middleware to redirect to an install action under certain circumstances.

Within my startup.cs I've added the middleware above the app.UseMvc middleware;

```
 app.SetInstall();
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

This is my invoke method inside my SetInstall middleware

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {


        if (isInstallerRunInstance())
        {
            if (!context.Request.GetEncodedUrl().Contains("install"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/install", false);
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
```

isInstallerRunInstance checks the underlying system to see if this is a candidate for the install action. 
If it is, and the install url hasn't been called, it will redirect to the install method.

This works ok - my problem occurs with subsequent requests.
Having completed this initial redirect via the root to install , I try a root request, it still redirects to /install even though the install has completed and isInstallerRunInstance returns false.

To further debug this, I placed the following line into the invoke method at the top before any other code is executed in the method;

```
   var url = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
```

The debugger tells me the url is http://localhost:8000/install, even though I requested the root and no redirect has been requested at this point.

Even more baffling - If I then go back to startup.cs and comment out the use of my middleware entirely then clean and rebuild the problem remains. I debug and request the root path, it still redirects to /install.
There doesn't appear to be any localhost cookies, I can't see anywhere this could be cached.

Perhaps there is something I am missing regarding the Redirect method or default caching in .net core.

I'm totally mystified. Any help, please?

Comment: Your browser could be doing the redirect? Or are you getting the 302 redirect in your browser?

Comment: Chrome is telling me it's a 301 redirect. The network tab in the debugger sees localhost, the status code is 301. The next item in the call stack is the /install url. Also worth noting, the same behaviour happens in in firefox and edge/IE - the initial redirect behaviour is correct, then on refresh it isn't anymore.

Comment: 301 redirect is permanent. But I thought you are issuing a non-permanent (i.e. 302) redirect? Issuing a 301 makes the browser remember it and make a 307 redirect before calling the app.

Comment: You'd be correct that it should be showing a 302, given the false flag. If I remove the middleware entirely though by commenting it out - the browser still performs this redirect to /install - almost as though it is remembering it from a cache. This project is currently inside the default .net core web app template, in an effort to remove any other factors.

Comment: Could you try resetting your Chrome cache a bit: http://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects/304600#304600 ?

Comment: I cleared the cache in chrome, when I did this the 302 redirect was recognised - I'd previously had it set as a 301 and this had been cached. Now solved - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this case is that the permanent parameter for Redirect had been true in the first version. This issued a 301 permanent redirect to the browser, making it cache it. That's why it won't change.

Clearing the cache per https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects/304600#304600 solved the issue.